# How do I use sendmail instead of mail to send via PHP?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a code that sends email like this, but I'd rather use `sendmail` instead of the default php mailer because I want to skip some php.ini settings:

```
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Subject.";
    $header = "From: Me <me@me.com>\r\n"; 
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $header.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
    $header.= sprintf("Content-Type: %s; charset=\"%s\"","text/html","utf-8")."\n\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $html_msg, $header);
```

What do I need to change to use `/usr/sbin/sendmail`?

Could I use `popen`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix-like system, then PHP's "default mailer" *is* sendmail, so you don't actually have to change anything if that's all you need.

For more details, you can see the relevant php.ini configuration options in the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

If you don't want to use `mail()`, then yes, you could talk to sendmail with `popen`, though you may instead want to use a third-party mailer package such as [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org), which (besides being able to send email via smtp/sendmail/postfix) also makes it easier to ensure that sent emails are properly formatted.